# What does "validating install" mean when installing Acrobat updates?

Tags: meaning

[image]

I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate and Adobe Acrobat DC 21.1.20135.421056.

Comment: It’s just the installation checking that everything went right.

Comment: @Xanne thanks I was curious what the validation is performing. The question was aimed at technical "super users" but those are rare on https://superuser.com/, where I had posted the question.

Comment: **As asked,** this question is on-topic here. If you want to know *what is actually being validated,* I suggest asking a more precise question on Superuser.

Comment: People on ELU are taking the question "what does XY mean" to literally be "what do the words X and Y used in combination mean"?? 

Also wouldn't such a question actually be off-topic since the meaning of two words can be easily looked up in commonly available references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Validation in computing ensures that the data entered is sensible and reasonable.

***[Validation or data validation](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/d/datavali.htm)***

> means checking or verifying any data that comes into the computer. This process helps ensure the data has not been compromised or corrupted during transmission.

> Performing data validation is important to ensure that incoming data is accurate, complete, and it has not been corrupted in any way.

(computerhope.com/jargon)

Answer (score 3):

Installation is the process of installing. The message should be “validating installation”. This tells the user that the software is checking that it is installing properly.

Adobe’s version of the message is merely a jargon extension of the meaning of a verb, using it as a noun. Install = installation.

The verb is

> *Install* transitive verb:
>
> to set up for use or service
> “had an exhaust fan installed in the kitchen”
> “install software”
>
> intransitive verb
>
> “to be set up for use or service : to undergo installation”
>
> “The software installs automatically.”
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/install)

The same fate has recently befallen the verb *build*, where pretentious television presentation now talks of *the build* for the process of building.

Comment: install means installation. They always shorten everthing.